# Select/click on checkbox by labelin Selenium

Tags: java, user-interface, selenium, testing, checkbox

I have the following html code and would like to select checkbox by label:

```
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="searchResult(this,'8')" id="catalog-8"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="catalog-8">
    my-assortment </label>
```

in the above example, by the value "my-assortment"

I tried this: `//label[containts('my-assortment')]` but it does not work.

More exactly, I want to write something like this:

```
//input[@type='checkbox'] which has "id" of the value of "for" 
  in label[contains(., 'my-assortment')]
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Can you not do the 'FindBy' using the checkboxes' 'id' value of 'catalog-8'?

Comment: spelled correct `containts`?

Comment: [error] Element //label[contains('my-assortment')] not found

Comment: @Brian how does it look like then?

Comment: What you have in your question is an 'Xpath' value.  Try replacing that value with the ID value.

Comment: ID Value? Unfortunately I am new in Selenium.

Comment: @javadeveloper - id="catalog-8".

Comment: I do not quite understand what do you mean? how? this id is dynamic. my goal is to click on the checkbox which has a specific value. I also edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `//label[containts('my-assortment')]`

First of all, this is not `containts` - it should be `contains` (watch the extra `t`). And, you are not using `contains()` correctly. It should be:

```
//label[contains(., 'my-assortment')]
```

Also, if you want to click the input element by label, [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) would help here:

```
//label[contains(., 'my-assortment')]/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']
```

Comment: Sorry. but it should not work, because it will select the first checkbox in this sibling. I give more info in the post now.